# bigcommerce display a product's categories on product display page

Tags: categories, bigcommerce, pdp

Looking to display all the categories that the specific product is in, on it's product display page. (in code for all products of course)

trying to get stencil's code for displaying like:

each top level category and then the subcategories within it. I have tried code for categories, but not seeming to work on product page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list out the categories that a product is in on the PDP using `product.category`. However, since this is an array, you will probably want to loop through it and give it some formatting. Here is an example:

```
<ul>
  {{#each product.category}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

If you only want to show the child categories (not the parent category), try this code:

```
<ul>
  {{#each product.category}}
    <li>{{last (split this '/')}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Reference: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/theme-objects/product

Comment: This pulls the data, perfectly, there's a way to separate like the top level category also right?

Comment: @M21 I have edited my answer to add an additional code sample that only displays the most-child category (not the parent categories).

Comment: Awesome I've been trying to work on that and that gives me a lot of the syntax to get it closer to my goal, I definitely want to omit the topmost level category which that does, and then I'm just trying to separate the 2nd level (as a heading) and then the 3rd level listed out. (I searched the link you sent but couldn't really find a syntax example of like first, last, etc.

Comment: That gets a bit more complex. But you can try things like {{#each (split this '/')}}{{#if @index '===' 1}}<h2>{{this}}</h2>{{/if}}{{#if @last}}<p>{{this}}</p>{{/if}}{{/each}} inside the each product.category loop. Hope this helps!

Comment: I figured it did, thank you I am just trying to learn these syntaxes so I can do some of this stuff! your help has been perfect!